# Select address from parent

Tags: php, mysql

I do have a table with locations like this:

```
ID | NAME   | ADDRESS   | PARENT_ID
 1 | name A | address A |      NULL
 2 | name B | NULL      |         1
```

Locations with a parent location do not always have an address (in case it's the same as the parent).

```
CREATE TABLE `location2` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_parent_location` int(5) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `location2` (`id`, `name`, `address`, `id_parent_location`) VALUES
(1, 'NAME A', 'ADDRESS A', NULL),
(2, 'NAME B', NULL, 1);
```

Anyone who can help me? Thanks!

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN `address` IS NULL THEN (SELECT `address` FROM `location` WHERE `id` = `id_parent_location`)
    ELSE `address`
END
FROM `location` WHERE `id` = 2
```

So in case of id=2 I want to show "name B" and "address A".

Comment: This looks like a hierarchy. How many levels can it have? If it has a dynamic number of levels you'll need MySQL 8.x, not MySQL 5.x. What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: A parent can have childs. No more hierarchy.